# Ajax - compare the value returned by success function

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to display a table row at the ajax request success.

```
    success : function(data)
                    {
                        if(data.status === "success")
                        {
                            $(parent_row).remove();
                            alert_box("success", "<?php echo 'keyword deleted successfully'; ?>", "#msg");

                       //display the table row
                            if(data.result == 0)
                            {
                                $("#no_result").show();
                            }
                        }

                    }
```

i want to compare the value returned by success function to be compared with an integer but the above code is not working i also want to display the table row having id "#no_result".

this is the console.log(data) result {"status":"success","result":0}

this is my controller function.

```
     public function delete_keywords()
{
    $this->load->model(array('Keywords','Keyword_topics'));
    $keyword = $this->input->post('keyword',TRUE);
    if(isset($keyword) && $keyword != '')
    {

        $this->Keywords->delete_records(array('kwd_id' => $keyword['k_id']));

        $this->Keyword_topics->delete_records(array('tkw_kwd_id' => $keyword['k_id']));
        $get_all_keywords = $this->Keywords->get_all_records();

        $count_ext_kwd=count($get_all_keywords);
        echo json_encode(array('status' => 'success','result' => $count_ext_kwd));

    }

}
```

I have faced a problem,i have a table (id, keywords, topics) containing inserted data,if no records is found in the table display "no records found".when insert only one(row) data ,then refresh the page,after delete the data..the message not display.

Comment: try `parseInt(data.result) == 0`

Comment: if you `console.log(data)` and see how the data is being sent from the server, most probably `json`, you might get some idea. Also, if you want to do a type match too, use `===` in place of just `==`. If the data is in json, you can use `obj = JSON.parse(data)`, then access the values in **status** and **result** , using `obj.status` and `obj.result` respectively

Comment: whether `alert_box` is appearing

Comment: Most browsers have a developer tool these days where you can step through javascript code and look at the returning http messages from ajax commands.

       "the ajax result {"status":"success","result":0}"

is ambiguous, is that the value of data? Also if this is the success callback, why do you need to check the status again?

Comment: @mane  console.log(data) value is Object {status: "success", result: 0}

Answer (score 1):

You need to use parseJSON to parse the response data. To show the table row, first console '#no_result'. So that you can know whether it presents or not. Finally we can go for '.show()'. Because your element might not be presented.

```
success : function(data)
                    {
                        // add this line to your code 
                        parsedObj = jQuery.parseJSON(data); 
                        // use parsedObj below
                        if(parsedObj.status === "success")
                        {
                            $(parent_row).remove();
                            alert_box("success", "<?php echo 'keyword deleted successfully'; ?>", "#msg");

                       //display the table row
                            if(parsedObj.result == 0)
                            {
                                //before use '.show()' check whether element presents. 
                                 console.log("#no_result");
                                // If element presents use '.show()' else, find its parent and finally use '.show()'.  
                                //$("#no_result").show();
                            }
                        }

                    }
```

Comment: when i check the console.log($("#no_result")); result,insert a data into the table and delete then "[tr#no_result, context: document, selector: "#no_result"]",but after refreshing the page,delete the record,the message doen't display,now the console.log($("#no_result")) result is "[context: document, selector: "#no_result"]"

Comment: two points, 1.whether jQuery.parseJSON helped for you?   2. I guess table row presents. so try $("#no_result").show()

Answer (score 0):

Then you could try something like this, hope it works

```
success : function(data)
                    {
                        var resObj = JSON.parse(data);
                        if(resObj.status === "success")
                        {
                            $(parent_row).remove();
                            alert_box("success", "<?php echo 'keyword deleted successfully'; ?>", "#msg");

                       //display the table row
                            if(resObj.result === 0)
                            {
                                $("#no_result").show();
                            }
                        }

                    }
```